# Linq Methods

Tags: c#, linq

Linq in general, has extensions methods(at IEnumerable) like Where, Select, OrderBy. But use another methods like string.StartsWith.

Where can I find a list with all methods supported, for Linq to SQL and Linq to Entities?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's a list of all supported methods for LINQ to entities:

[Supported and Unsupported LINQ Methods (LINQ to Entities)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/supported-and-unsupported-linq-methods-linq-to-entities)

Answer (score 6):

For LINQ to SQL:

[Data Types and Functions (LINQ to SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386970.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You could start with 101 Linq Samples.

There is a [C# version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx) and a [VB.Net Version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb688088.aspx). The C# and VB.Net are broken out differently and the VB.Net version has a section specific to Linq to SQL.

You can also check out the MSDN section on [Linq to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976.aspx).

For Linq to Entities check out this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550.aspx) link on **Supported and Unsupported Methods** (LINQ to Entities).

Answer (score -1):

You can use Visual Studio's class browser to check the Enumerable class, which contains all LINQ extension methods.

Comment: Not all LINQ extension methods are supported by LINQ to Entities.